# Segue dosent work at all

Tags: ios, segue

I am working to get the segue right but I am not getting it at all.  I have experince in game programming but is a beginner in objective c.  I am trying to take a photo in the app and then display it onto another view controller so that the user can crop it.
This is my Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CropViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UIImagePickerController *picker;
UIImage *image;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
CropViewController *cropVC;
}
- (IBAction)TakePhoto;
```

My Viewcontroller.m is

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CropViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)TakePhoto {
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CropImage" sender:self];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel  :(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CropImage"])
{
    CropViewController *CropViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    CropViewController.theImage = picker;
    // Similar to [segue.destinationViewController setTheImage:yourImage];
}
}
-(void)createDirectory:(NSString *)ShoesDirectory atFilePath:(NSString *)filePath
{
NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:ShoesDirectory];
NSError *error;

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
                               withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                attributes:nil
                                                     error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
}
}
```

My CropViewController is

```
@interface CropViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *theImage;
@property UIImage *picker;
```

I want the user to push the camera button in viewcontroller and then take a picture then the picture is displayed to CopViewController where I have put and UImageView.  If i use the above code it builds however the app stops the moment I push the Camera button.
UPDATE Here is the crash I did not touch the App Delagate

```
@autoreleasepool {
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

> 2013-07-19 14:11:25.226 [4758:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
>   () has no segue with identifier
>   'CropImage''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x343192a3 0x3bffd97f 0x3632ce31 0x891ef 0x3620c0c5 0x3620c077 0x3620c055 0x3620b90b 0x3620be01 0x361345f1
>   0x36121801 0x3612111b 0x37e285a3 0x37e281d3 0x342ee173 0x342ee117
>   0x342ecf99 0x3425febd 0x3425fd49 0x37e272eb 0x36175301 0x88eed
>   0x3c434b20) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

Comment: Can you post a stack trace or the error in the console for the crash?

Comment: I think a few of the answers are partially correct.  You don't need to both push the picker view controller *and* perform a segue.  You want to do one or the other.  The error from the crash is indicating it doesn't know about the segue "CropImage".  So your view controller must not have a segue with that name.

Comment: So where am I suppose to delete? Should I delete         CropViewController.theImage = picker; ? Sorry Im too new to objective c

Answer (score 0):

Take out this line:

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether it uses segue or not, But [here](https://github.com/raviparmar/GKImagePicker) is the exact example of what u are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry this looks good but is this linked with the camera so like u take a picture inside the app and then it just automattically  lets you crop?

Comment: I don't know much about this demo, but 'm also trying to achieve similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this. You need to have a UINavigationController in your story board. To do this take your first scene, click on it and go to tabs at top of xcode and do Editor>Embed in>Navigation controller, check the button to set the navigation controller as inital scene. Add the following code to hide the navbar at top.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```